# Spring HibernateDaoSupport creates multiple sessions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions, spring-orm

I am using Struts2.3 + Spring 3.2.6 + Hibernate 3.X for my web application.

I am using annotations to manage the transaction. 
My DAO class is as below.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, rollbackFor={Exception.class})
public class CustomerDAOImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements CustomerDAO{

    //adds the customer
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
    public void addCustomer(Customer customer){
        Session session = getSession();
        System.out.println("M1() Hash Code: --->"+session.hashCode()+ " Thread id: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
        //session.save(customer);
    }

    //return all the customers in list
    // @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = {Exception.class})
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Customer> listCustomer(){
        Session session = getSession();
        System.out.println("M2() Hash Code: --->"+session.hashCode()+ " Thread id: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
        return null; //logic to get the list based on condition

    }
```

These methods will be called from service layer and it is like below;

```
customerDAO.addCustomer(customer);
customerDAO.listCustomer();
```

I am getting **different sessions for same thread** when the above code is executed.

**Output:**

```
M1() Hash Code: --->5026724 Thread id: 21
M2() Hash Code: --->8899550 Thread id: 21
```

Due to this, **if any exception comes** in method2() the data which is persisted using method1() **is not rollback**.

Please let me know, how to get the single session based on thread (if i go for my own HibernateFactory i lose transaction management by Spring) with out loosing spring transaction management.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Hibernate make your DAO class to extend HibernateDaoSupport. Now you can get session from getHibernateTemplate() method. That way you can have the session managed by spring-hibernate

You can try this  -

appContext.xml

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
         <tx:method name="submit*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false" rollback-for="Exception"/>
</tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="appControllerTransactionPointCuts"
            expression="execution(* com.test.customer.bo.Custom.*(..))" />
<aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="appControllerTransactionPointCuts" />
    </aop:config>
```

Remove -

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

from appcontext.xml

Now AOP should manage transactions.

How Transactions work -
Suppose you are persisting objects in multiple DAO methods and you want them all to happen in one transaction, then you have to apply transaction at the service layer method where the DAO methods are getting called. For e., in my case the service layer is com.test.customer.bo.Custom.*

If you are not doing so, then each of your DAO method will be executed in a separate transaction and will get persisted to database if no exception occurs. If exception occur in method2() of DAO layer it will not rollback method1() as it is already committed.

Comment: Also add tx:annotationdriven in your spring application context so that spring will manage transaction

Comment: i have tried it. but still transaction is not rollback.

Comment: Have you added <aop:config/> or <aop:aspectj-autoproxy /> since you are also using AOP

Comment: try this - only with xml, no annotation                                                            <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
      <tx:method name="get*" read-only="false" rollback-for="YourException"/>
      <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>                                                                                              <aop:config>
 <aop:advisor order="3" advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut="your.pointcut()"/>
</aop:config>             This has worked for me

Comment: i added adivce & config tags also. But no use.

Comment: Your method name starts with user* so in the tx: advice change it to user* instead of submit*

Comment: altered the question based on root cause. Please check it @Waqar

Comment: I think i got your problem. You are applying transaction at DAO layer. So your method M1() is executed in 1 transaction and your method M2() is executed in another transaction. If you want both your methods M1() and M2() of the DAO layer to be executed in 1 transaction you should remove the annotation at the DAO layer and place it on the calling method at service layer (the same method of service layer which calls M1() and M2() of DAO layer).

Comment: If you refer to my answer carefully I am referring to the service layer package e.g., com.test.customer.bo. is my service layer package.    I hope this will solve your problem of different sessions @user1225623

Comment: When exception occurs in M2 it has got nothing to do with M1 in your case as both are in different transactions. So since M1 succeeded without exception it got persisted to database and cannot be rolled back. So move your annotation at service layer where both M! and M2 are getting called.